# How can i send binary data via websocket in safari5

Tags: safari, binary, websocket

I found out that safari 5.1 is using a draft version of websocket, i think it is hybi-00.

I am trying to send binary data with the following code:

```
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(64);
    var dv = new DataView(ab);
    dv.setUint32(0, 1);
    websock.send(ab);
```

But the server received a text message containing "[object ArrayBuffer]" instead of a binary message. The hex dump of the data received by server is :

```
    00 5b 6f 62 6a 65 63 74 20 41 72 72 61 79 42 75     .[object.ArrayBu
    66 66 65 72 5d ff -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --     ffer].
```

Obviously, the javascript convert the ArrayBuffer object to a string, and send the string to server.

So, How can i send the binary data in ArrayBuffer?

Comment: The code looks fine. Propably Safari5 doesn't support binary messages at all? You could propably test to send an ArrayBufferView (like an Uint8Array) instead of the ArrayBuffer. However standard webkit implemented this overload for send even much later than the send(ArrayBuffer), therefore I think it also won't work.

Comment: I have to give up, i have spent too much time on safari5. my web app will not support safari5...

Answer (score 1):

The hybi 00 / hixie 76 draft specification for WebSockets does not include a number of features found in the final  version, including binary messages. Unfortunately there is no way to support native binary websocket messages in the hybi00 browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you could try:

websock.send (ab.buffer);